# Why is 之 used in 忍耐是幸福之门的一把钥匙?

Tags: grammar, particles

Why is 之 used in this sentence?

> 忍耐是幸福之门的一把钥匙.

Cant it just as easily be substituted with 的?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

之 and 的 are essentially synonyms for different contexts.

之 is mostly used in set phrases, idioms, proverbs, poems, etc. (Also math with percents and such: 百分**之**百 100 points **out of** 100. )

的 is more fit for colloquial contexts.

Since 忍耐是幸福之门的一把钥匙 "Patience is the key to the door of happiness" is a phrase, it is fit to use 之.

Comment: For context, in earlier periods of the language "之" was the only way to say "的" so in the modern language 之 has a more formal or poetic usage. It's like how "thou" in English has a special connotation that is slightly different from how it was actually used in Middle English

Answer (score 5):

Another reason is to avoid using the same word again and again in the sentence. To make it easier to read and understand, in sentences where you get related 的, this adds variety.

For instance:

```
忍耐是幸福之门的一把钥匙
```

is easier to understand than:

```
忍耐是幸福的门的一把钥匙
```

Comment: also a good point!

Answer (score 0):

usually, you may translate x之y to "y of x". Not applicable in ancient Chinese.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why it is not applicable on ancient Chinese, and give an example?

Comment: This is only part of an answer. Please improve your answer by providing more information. Low quality answers may be removed.

Comment: in ancient Chinese, 之 has multiple meanings. can be a pronoun, it, for example.